# GlassFish 4: How to rotate log every day

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-4

I am using Glassfish 4. I would like to rotate the log every day. That means I like a new log for each day. I have tried changing properties at the admin console at http:localhost:4848 but it is not working for me. Here is what I have tried:

```
 Configurations\default-config\Logger Settings and I set the checkbox for Rotation on Date Change
```

and also

```
 Configurations\server-config\Logger Settings and I set the checkbox for Rotation on Date Change
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: After modifying these settings, did you restart the domain?

Comment: What do you mean by restart the domain? I stop and restart the glassfish server using Netbeans.

Comment: When you restart GlassFish, is the Rotation on Date Change check box checked under server-config -> Logger Settings?

Comment: Also, you can check `<glassfish_home>/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/logging.properties` and make sure this property is set correctly:
`com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.rotationOnDateChange=true`

Comment: @IanEvans The Rotation on Date Change check box is checked under server-config->Logger Settings when I restart Glassfish. I also look into the logging.properties file and the property rotationOnDateChange=true is set. Any other suggestions?

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that the setting of Rotation on Date Change is overridden by the File Rotation Limit setting. You might try setting the latter to 0 and then seeing if server.log gets rotated at midnight.

Comment: @IanEvans I cannot set the File Rotation Limit to 0. It gives me an error.

Answer (score 0):

you can use asadmin from command line:

```
./asadmin --host localhost --port 4848 --user admin set-com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.rotationOnDateChange=true
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can to configure the retention log, using

asadmin> set-log-attributes
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.maxHistoryFiles=10

[Source](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/gklmn.html)